# Add timestamp to the PDF file with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, trusted-timestamp

I am trying to add a TSA Timestamp to the pdf document using Apache PDFBox 2.0.8.

this is the metod for setting up&process timestamping:

```
@Override
    public void timestampPDFDocument() throws IOException, SignatureException, COSVisitorException {
        final PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setType(COSName.DOC_TIME_STAMP);
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(COSName.getPDFName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        signature.setReason("test");

        final PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(dataSrv.currentCtxFile());

        final TimestampPDFImplementation sig = new TimestampPDFImplementation(cHTTPProxyPassword, cHTTPProxyUsername, ctstHttpUrl, signingCrt);

        SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
        pdf.addSignature(signature, sig, options);

        pdf.save(dataSrv.createNewAndHandBufferedOutputStream());
        pdf.close();
    }
```

I am storing file per request in memory for easier manipulation of "shared resource", that's where pdf comes from on load:

```
PDDocument.load(dataSrv.currentCtxFile());
```

My implementation of `SignatureInterface`:

```
public class TimestampPDFImplementation implements SignatureInterface {

    String cHTTPProxyPassword;
    String cHTTPProxyUsername;
    String ctstHttpUrl;
    String signingCrt;

    public TimestampPDFImplementation(String cHTTPProxyPassword, String cHTTPProxyUsername, String ctstHttpUrl, String signingCrt) {
        this.cHTTPProxyPassword = cHTTPProxyPassword;
        this.cHTTPProxyUsername = cHTTPProxyUsername;
        this.ctstHttpUrl = ctstHttpUrl;
        this.signingCrt = signingCrt;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream inputStream) throws SignatureException, IOException {
        TElHTTPTSPClient tspClient = new TElHTTPTSPClient();
        TElHTTPSClient httpClient = new TElHTTPSClient();
        TElMemoryCertStorage certStorage = new TElMemoryCertStorage();

        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(cHTTPProxyPassword) &&
                !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(cHTTPProxyUsername)) {
            // set the http client

            TElHTTPRequestParams requestParams = new TElHTTPRequestParams();
            requestParams.setUsername(cHTTPProxyUsername);
            requestParams.setPassword(cHTTPProxyPassword);

            httpClient.setRequestParameters(requestParams);
        }

        tspClient.setHTTPClient(httpClient);

        tspClient.setHashAlgorithm(SBConstants.SB_ALGORITHM_DGST_SHA512);
        tspClient.setURL(ctstHttpUrl);

        certStorage.add(loadCrt(signingCrt, ""), false);
        httpClient.setCertStorage(certStorage);

        tspClient.setIncludeCertificates(true);
        tspClient.setOnHTTPError(setErrEvntHandler());
        httpClient.setOnCertificateValidate(crtValidateEvent());

        TElTSPReply tspReply = new TElTSPReply();
        tspClient.timestamp(ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream), tspReply);

        tspClient.Destroy();

        if (tspReply.FailureInfo != 0 || tspReply.ServerResult != 0)
            throw new SignatureException(
                    String.format("timestamping service error; FailureInfo:  %s, ServerResult: %s", tspReply.FailureInfo, tspReply.ServerResult)
            );

        return tspReply.ReplyCMS;
    }


    private TSBHTTPTSPErrorEvent setErrEvntHandler() {
        TSBHTTPTSPErrorEvent.Callback callback = (tObject, i) -> {
            System.out.println();
        };

        return new TSBHTTPTSPErrorEvent(callback);
    }

    private TSBCertificateValidateEvent crtValidateEvent() {
        TSBCertificateValidateEvent.Callback callback = (tObject, tElX509Certificate, tElX509CertificateValidateResult) -> {

//            tElX509Certificate.loadFromFileAuto(signingCrt, "");
            tElX509CertificateValidateResult.Validity = TSBCertificateValidity.cvOk;
            tElX509CertificateValidateResult.Reason = 0;
        };

        return new TSBCertificateValidateEvent(callback);
    }

    private TElX509Certificate loadCrt(String filename, String crtPass) {
        TElX509Certificate certificate = new TElX509CachedCertificate();
        certificate.loadFromFileAuto(filename, crtPass);
        return certificate;
    }
}
```

Signing logic should be fine, that I verified earlier.

My problem with all this is that `byte[] sign(InputStream inputStream)` method is not ever being executed. No exceptions thrown.
Size of saved PDF is increased but when timestamping logic is bypassed there is no effect.

`timestampPDFDocument()` is called from injected `@Service` into the application event listener and called from there.

So, what am I missing for properly executing TSA timestamping here and why  is `sign()` implementation not executed?

Comment: use saveIncremental instead of save and the current version is 2.0.9

Comment: well, it did something, but I can't tell what cause the resulting file size is less than input. and file is not readable by pdf viewer

Comment: target file name must be different to source file. Is it?

Comment: Also check whether there is any log output.

Comment: yes, I am using ByteArrayInputStream as an input for .load() method, and I did pdf.saveIncremental("qwer.pdf"); with the filename so it's definitely not the same.
I have to be missing something more...
I made an observation: even with saveIncremental() the sign() method is not being called without passing SignatureOptions into the signature. this object is empty in my case, so it may be connected somehow.

Comment: nothing interesting is being logged, unfortunately

Comment: "the sign() method is not being called without passing SignatureOptions into the signature" - does this mean it is called if the SignatureOptions  is passed? Or that it never being called regardless if passed or not?

Comment: Please share source and destination files. I wonder what's in the destination. `pdf.saveIncremental("qwer.pdf")` cannot work, there is no `saveIncremental` method that accepts a string.